# Installing Gems on Amazon AWS with Elastic Beanstalk for non Rails ruby script

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I automatically install Gems on deployment with Elastic Beanstalk for non Rails ruby scripts?

Will a "Gemfile" in root still get run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a Gemfile in your app source will be processed. In addition you also have the option of locally packaging your dependencies in `vendor/cache`. See [this](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx2XVRWSS4E971S/Locally-Packaging-Gem-Dependencies-for-Ruby-Applications-in-Elastic-Beanstalk) blog post for more details.